# How do I implement a LINQ-type IComparer<T> overload where T implements IComparable<T>?

Tags: c#

I am implementing a class that in the style of the LINQ libraries has an overload for a custom IComparer. (e.g. OrderBy: `OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)` and `OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IComparer<TKey>)`).

I would like to implement the 2-argument overload in terms of the 1-argument overload. Something like the following:

```
T Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    // Do something that returns a T
}

T Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    IComparer<T> comparer = /*what goes here?*/;
    return Method(collection, comparer);
}
```

In this respect, the question boils down to asking, how do I obtain an instance of IComparer for a type that implements IComparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Comparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx).